# Trigonometric Identies: Given $\sin(3a)=2 \sin(a)$ find $\cos(2a)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

> $$\sin(3a)=2 \sin(a)$$

What if I first did was split $\sin(3a)$ using the addition formula, thus giving me:

$\sin(2a)\cos(a)+\cos(2a)\sin(a)$ $\Rightarrow$

Then I split the double angles using the double angle formulas.

$2\sin(a)\cos^2(a)+(1-2\sin^2(a))\sin(a)=2\sin(a)$

Then I simplified that and got:

$2\sin(a)(\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a))=\sin(a) \Rightarrow \cos(2a)=1/2$

This is only one answer, and I don't know if it is correct. Any hints?

Comment: By eliminating the factor $\sin a$ you lost a solution.

Comment: So, what would I do to find it?

Comment: Write your equation as ${\sin} a(2({\cos}^2 a-\sin^2a)-1)=0$ and conclude that either the first or the second factor (or both) must be zero?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974166/trigonometric-identities-given-that-2-cos3a-cosa-find-cos2a/2974258#2974258

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!)

Use the identity $\sin 3a = 3 \sin a - 4 \sin^3 a$ and set equal to $2 \sin a$ to get

$$3 \sin a - 4 \sin^3 a = 2 \sin a$$

Bring over the $2 \sin a$ to get

$$\sin a - 4 \sin^3 a = 0$$

Factor out $\sin a$ to get

$$\sin a (1-4 \sin^2 a) = 0$$

Now for a little trick...using $\cos 2a = 1-2 \sin^2 a$, we can rewrite $1-4 \sin^2 a$ as:

$$2 - 4 \sin^2 a = 2 \cos 2a \Rightarrow 1-4 \sin^2 a = 2 \cos 2a -1 $$ to get

$$\sin a (2 \cos 2a -1) = 0$$

We have either $\sin a = 0$ or $(2\cos 2a - 1) = 0$, but as we're interested in $\cos 2a$ we have

$$2 \cos 2a = 1$$

Now all we need to do is divide by $2$ to get

$$\bbox [white,5px, border:2px solid black] {\cos 2a = \dfrac {1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct except for a small problem.

Note that when you cancelled $\sin (\alpha)$ from both sides you have to make sure to add the solutions of  $\sin (\alpha)=0$ as well.

Also, you could have used the identity, $$2\cos ^2 (\alpha ) = 1+ \cos (2\alpha)$$ to have a shorter proof, but what you did in just fine.

Comment: But, my textbook says there are two answers.

Comment: Please check my edited version. I have addressed the other solution.

Comment: So in order to solve, would I have my sin(a) as $0$? I don't understand sorry. I know what you are trying to say, but there should be 2 answers for cos(2a)? Maybe I misinterpreted what you said.

Comment: $\sin (\alpha)=0 \implies \cos (2\alpha ) = 1-2\sin ^2 (\alpha) =1$

Comment: Oh, haha, I forgot about that identity, thanks!